# How to set a Calendar alert for AFTER completion of an event?

Tags: calendar, ical, alarm

I would like to set calendar alerts to happen at the scheduled completion time of my events - whatever that may be.  I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.  You can create alarms that go off before an event starts, at the start time, or a fixed number of minutes after start time.  But is there a way to set an alarm that triggers AT OR AFTER the completion time of an event, without having to specify the exact date & time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems possible now to add an additional alert and choose a time *after* the event's start time. So if you need to pickup your kids after a 2hr game, and it takes 20mins to get there, under custom alert choose **100 minutes after**
[image]

Comment: Ah look at that, they must've been listening!  LOL  Thanks, I've marked this as the correct answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Just enter an alert at a customized time (which is equal to end of the event).

This works for iCal 5 (Mac OS X 10.7):

[image: iCal 5]

and also for iCal 7 (Mac OS X 10.9). It looks a bit different though:

[image: iCal 7]

Comment: My request was specific to not having to input the exact time & date.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute Oh sorry, i misread that

Answer (score 0):

Well there doesn't appear to be any actual proper solution to this, so I have resorted to simply putting an alert in at the pre-set duration of the event.  Definitely not what I was hoping for but... it's the best that I could come up with.  This gets me an alert at the end of the time block, but unfortunately won't automatically adjust if I alter the duration of a block.